# Compressing a 2D array

Tags: c

I would like to compress a 2d array from the following input

```
Enter the array size (rowSize, colSize):
4 4
Enter the matrix (4x4):
1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

to this, where the number of 1's and 0's are specified.

```
compress2D():
1 3 0 1
0 2 1 2
1 4
0 4
```

the following is my code

```
void compress2D(int data[SIZE][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
int i , j , counter = 0, tempInt = data[0][0];
for (i = 0 ; i < rowSize ; i++)
{
    for (j = 0 ; j < colSize ; j++ )
    {
        if (data[i][j] == tempInt) 
            counter++ ; 
        else
        {
            printf("%d %d " , tempInt,counter);
            tempInt = data[i][j];
            counter = 1;

        }   
    }
    if(counter!=0)
        printf("%d %d",tempInt, counter);
    counter = 0 ;
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

however this is my output

```
compress2D(): 
1 3 0 1
0 2 1 2
1 4
1 0 0 4
```

all inputs will be binary

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `tempInt` be set at the beginning of each new line?

Comment: Nice question. You pose a clear and specific problem, along with expected inputs and outputs and an attempted solution. Nice break from the crap I normally see here.

Comment: Your program is small enough to step through it with a debugger, or litter it with print statements, to see what precisely is going on. You can even work out all the individual steps by hand, with pen and paper, to find your mistake.

Comment: @clemens. Good catch. `data[i][j] == tempInt` toggles for the row causing the problem.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Other than the specific problems you are facing, is this the required algorithm?  Seems like you could compress it better than this by just encoding the number of sequential 0 and 1s a) regardless of rows (just continue top to bottom, left to right) and not introducing the 0 or 1 before the count - with only 2 you can infer that each count changes the value it represents,

Comment: @LoztInSpace Yes, actually. The output may be longer than the input in some cases, but this is the algorithm that i am tasked with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to reset `tempInt` each time you start a new row

```
void compress2D(int data[SIZE][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int i, j, counter = 0, tempInt = data[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
    {
        tempInt = data[i][0];                        // <--------

        for (j = 0; j < colSize; j++)
        {
            if (data[i][j] == tempInt)
                counter++;
            else
            {
                printf("%d %d ", tempInt, counter);
                tempInt = data[i][j];
                counter = 1;

            }
        }
        if (counter != 0)
            printf("%d %d", tempInt, counter);
        counter = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: can't believe i missed this out for hours

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/MJqKZT):

```
void compress2D(int data[SIZE][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int i , j , counter, tempInt;
    for (i = 0 ; i < rowSize ; i++)
    {
        tempInt = data[i][0];
        counter = 1;

        for (j = 1 ; j < colSize ; j++ )
        {
            if (data[i][j] == tempInt) 
                counter++ ; 
            else
            {
                printf("%d %d " , tempInt,counter);
                tempInt = data[i][j];
                counter = 1;
            }   
        }
        if(counter)
            printf("%d %d",tempInt, counter);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Updated after last comment of OP(*`0 1 1 2 0 1` , there are some cases where the output will be longer than the input itself*).

Comment: This won't work because the output always has the 1's first. And it won't work for a row like `0110`.

Comment: @user3386109 I didn't gave a thought on the printing sequence. Updated!!!

Comment: @user3386109 There is no such pattern in OP question. So I'm not sure if this is what is desired. I think OP should edit/comment on this.

Comment: @JoeyNgo What is expected output for pattern `0 1 1 0`?

Comment: 0 1 1 2 0 1 , there are some cases where the output will be longer than the input itself